# Reasons file permissions may not match argument given to mkdir in php?

Tags: php, file-permissions

I'm trying to debug a strange file permission issue involving php, and have exhausted the obvious problems. Note that I'm not experienced with php, so it might be something dead-obvious.

I want the user to be able to create a folder and files via a web interface, and to be able to work with those files from a separate user account on the server for some backend work. The problem is that the created folders and files have no write or execute permissions for other users.

I don't have a lot of knowledge in this area, so my best hacky try was to see if explicitly passing 0777, even though it's the default, to the relevant mkdir fixed it. And also to every other mkdir call. And every chmod call.

As far as I can tell, the folder and files SHOULD be created with the right permissions. Does anyone know reasons the permissions might differ from what I naively expect?

Comment: Is this on windows? Windows ignores the the permissions, since it has it's own permissions system.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if this is UNIX you need to check the UMASK for the web server user, if this is windows, it ignores the permissions.

http://us.php.net/umask

Comment: The umask change is not permanent. I suppose that's a good thing. What determines the value-before-first-call?

Comment: depend on the way the user is setup in the system.  if you have access to the server, check the ~/.profile file